# Detect rotated-rectangle intersection

Tags: math, box2d

I want to test if a rotated rectangle intersects my camera's view frustrum (an axis aligned rectangle).

I was hoping there'd be a solution for this provided in Graphics Gems, but don't see one. This one looks close: http://www.ragestorm.net/tutorial?id=22 but the comments suggest that it does not work as published.

This question seems to have been asked a few times on SO over the years, but don't see a working example. Anyone have any pointers to anything? Maybe there's a static method I could lift from Box2d since certainly a test like this must be used somewhere in that code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track - box2d does have a method for this...

in b2CollidePolygon.cpp, there is the following method:

```
void b2CollidePolygons(b2Manifold* manifold,
    const b2PolygonShape* polyA, const b2Transform& xfA,
    const b2PolygonShape* polyB, const b2Transform& xfB)
```

As you can see, the results of the test is returned by `b2Manifold`.  The input to the test are two shapes (one would be the fixture for your body, the other would be your view), and the transformations for those shapes, which you can get from calling the `GetTransform` method of `b2Body`.

Comment: I'm guessing that since one of the rectangles is a view rectangle he doesn't actually have bodies to work with. But the transforms could be made easily enough like: b2Transform xfA( b2Vec2(x,y), angleInRadians);